# Using AsyncTask with Fragments,ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

How to implement AsyncTask I have fragment,what I should write in the line

```
listview = (ListView) ?????? findViewById(R.id.listviewget);
```

and if I put it in onCreateView

```
 listview = (ListView) veiw.findViewById(R.id.listviewget);
```

I got error below.All getting code  works because I have checked in activity and it got data from server but not works in fragments

> 01-22 21:59:32.850: E/ArrayAdapter(32155): You must supply a resource
>   ID for a TextView 01-22 21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main 01-22 21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID
>   to be a TextView 01-22 21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):     at
>   android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
>   01-22 21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362) 01-22
>   21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):    at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2075) 01-22
>   21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):    at
>   android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2004) 01-22
>   21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):    at
>   android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:856) 01-22
>   21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):    at
>   android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:916) 01-22
>   21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):    at
>   android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1857) 01-22
>   21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):    at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1905) 01-22
>   21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):    at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359) 01-22 21:59:32.890:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4531) 01-22 21:59:32.890:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:925) 01-22
>   21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):    at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359) 01-22 21:59:32.890:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4531) 01-22 21:59:32.890:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431) 01-22
>   21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):    at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359) 01-22 21:59:32.890:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4531) 01-22 21:59:32.890:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:801)
>   01-22 21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359) 01-22 21:59:32.890:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4531) 01-22 21:59:32.890:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431) 01-22
>   21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):    at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359) 01-22 21:59:32.890:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4531) 01-22 21:59:32.890:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
>   01-22 21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
>   01-22 21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399) 01-22
>   21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):    at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359) 01-22 21:59:32.890:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4531) 01-22 21:59:32.890:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431) 01-22
>   21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):    at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:11359) 01-22 21:59:32.890:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4531) 01-22 21:59:32.890:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1665)
>   01-22 21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2695) 01-22
>   21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 01-22
>   21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 01-22 21:59:32.890:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987) 01-22
>   21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-22
>   21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 01-22 21:59:32.890:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   01-22 21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 01-22
>   21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 01-22 21:59:32.890:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(32155): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.TextView 01-22 21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):
>     at
>   android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
>   01-22 21:59:32.890: E/AndroidRuntime(32155):  ... 39 more

```
public class MyLibrary  extends Fragment {
ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> data;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


public MyLibrary()
{

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Parse.initialize(getActivity(), "ASD", "ASD");
    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.getnewlay,container, false);
    new GetData().execute();
    return view;
}

private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Getting data...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("ASD");
        query.orderByDescending("_created_at");
        try {
            data= query.find();


        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        listview = (ListView) ?????? findViewById(R.id.listviewget);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.getnewlay);
        for (ParseObject name : data) {
            adapter.add((String) name.get("name"));
        }
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Means `R.layout.getnewlay` layout contain TextView but inside `RelativeLayout` so you will either assign any id to TextView and use another Constructor of `ArrayAdapter` which require TextView id:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.getnewlay,R.id.textView_Id);
```

or remove `RelativeLayout` layout from xml and make `TextView` as root View :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    .....
/>
```

> How to access View from Fragment layout in onPostExecute method:

Use `getView` method:

```
listview = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.listviewget);
```

Comment: Oh my God!! I forgot about layout with textview and write main layout instead  thanks you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Check your layout getnewlay. it should have only TextView as a parent in layout(not even any layout like Linear or relative layout)

or else you can put `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` instead of `R.layout.getnewlay`

Answer (score 1):

pass resource ID of your TextView in layout 'getnewlay' like

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.getnewlay, R.id.textViewResourceId_in_getnewlay)
```